# Spring Web Flow - How can I set up unit test with values already in conversationScope?

Tags: java, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I am working on a project using Spring Web Flow 2.0.

I am trying to unit test a flow that begins with a decision state. The decision state checks the value of an object that is on the `conversationScope`.   I cannot figure out how to insert a value into the `conversationScope` for the unit test.

I have tried:

```
getConversationScope().put("someName", value);
MockExternalContext context = new MockExternalContext();
startFlow(context);
```

However, it seems that when I call `startFlow(context)` the value is cleared.

I also tried:

```
MockExternalContext context = new MockExternalContext();
setCurrentState("someDecisionState");
resumeFlow(context)
```

But the test fails with an error telling me that I cannot resume from a decision state, only from a view state.

Does anyone know how I can insert mock values on the `conversationScope` so that I may test these cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not obvious, but I came up with this:

```
public void testFoo() {
    FlowExecution flowExecution = getFlowExecutionFactory().createFlowExecution(getFlowDefinition());
    updateFlowExecution(flowExecution);
    flowExecution.getConversationScope().put("fooBar", "goo");
    flowExecution.start(null, new MockExternalContext());        
    assertCurrentStateEquals("fooView");
}
```

I had to dig into the underlying `AbstractXmlFlowExecutionTests.startFlow()` to see how it was instantiating the `FlowExecution`, and copy and paste some of that into the unit test.

Here's the test web flow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <action-state id="decideFoo">
        <evaluate expression="conversationScope.fooBar" />
        <transition on="goo" to="fooView" />
        <transition on="gar" to="barView" />
    </action-state>

    <view-state id="fooView" />

    <view-state id="barView" />

</flow>
```

Comment: Nice, will try when I get a chance

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!   Seems like the key bit is using flowExecution.start(null, context),   as using startFlow(context) seems to clear out anything you had set up on your flowExecution.

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Yes, the startFlow(context) method creates a new FlowExecution behind the scenes.  With this example you can use your own FlowExecution, at the expense of writing more code to manage it somewhat manually.